# How to monitor the browsing content in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-browser

As a part of enterprise security, I need to restrict the default android browser to block some website.

I have implemented a background service that will notify me when user opens the browser.

How to get the website URL or browsing content while the user accesses a website ?

How to monitor it ?

Comment: as a part of your enterprise security, you can monitor the traffic in the responsible parts of the infrastructure (routers/firewalls etc). You are aware that all users of this enterprise security model, should have signed an agreement to be monitored, otherwise it's forbidden by law. Who did you say you were working for?

Comment: This app is for android devices that use GPRS/Wi-Fi connection. Hence, monitoring using routers/firewalls is not possible.

Comment: @androiduser: how did you get notification when user opens browser? please guide me through sample code or tutorial. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Far As I know, it is not possible to get current URL from default browser. If you want, you can implement your own browser using android web view and using web view client you can get what URL user is browsing by overriding

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
```

for more check below link

[Get the current page being viewed in the browser (Possible?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470434/get-the-current-page-being-viewed-in-the-browser-possible)