# Monitoring android default browser link click and its status in custom application

Tags: android, browser, monitoring, android-internet

We cannot monitor default browser links activity through either listeners or console logs since it is termed as a privacy violoation
Ref: [Get the current page being viewed in the browser (Possible?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470434/get-the-current-page-being-viewed-in-the-browser-possible)
I tried using my own custom web view to override default web links click events to detect but the Ref:problem is it works only if web pages are loaded in this own custom browser.
[How to make links open within webview or open by default browser depending on domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907045/how-to-make-links-open-within-webview-or-open-by-default-browser-depending-on-do)

Is there any way where in we can detect link clicks / page loads on default browser and use it in my custom app ?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I need it for keeping track of testing android phones.

Comment: From the first linky in your question, commonsware pointed this out that its not possible and is a violation so it would be a no-go.